# Put it simple or put it simply

Tags: phrases

> Let's put it simply: If the central government wanted to "eliminate"
>   the Dalai Lama, why has it waited for such a long time? Isn't it
>   foolish to take action against Dalai at such an old age?

I read this in Global Times. I gave a second thought on the usage of *put it simply* here and suspect that *put it simple* would be a better choice. Am I right?

**Edit**: I have seen *put it simple* and *simply put* more often, which is why I asked here.

Comment: No. Simply is an adverb whereas simple is an adjective. The "simply" is modifying "put"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simchona says, simply is an adverb modifying the verb so "put it simply" is correct.

Comment: It is possible that the OP is extrapolating from the similar, and correct, expression: "*Let's make it simple.*"